# Why do they prefer dynamic scheduling in this code snippet

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

I solved an exercise, where I had to implement SGD (stochastic gradient descent) with momentum. The exercise was to parallelize it afterwards.

My suggestion was as follow:

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
         const double nablaE_w = (1.0/double(B)) * (grad[i] + lambda * param[i]);
         mom_w[i] = beta * mom_w[i] - eta * nablaE_w;
         param[i] = param[i] + mom_w[i];
    }
```

I use `nowait` because after the `for`-loop the calculation is finished.

But on the solution they uses:

```
#pragma omp for schedule (dynamic, 64/sizeof(double)) nowait
```

Also after reading several stackoverflow-answers, I still cannot see the advantage of `scheduling(dynamic)` and why they uses the chunksize=8

I am careful when using schedule(dynamic) - actually I never use it, because I have no idea how to do it correctly.

Comment: Who wrote the solution? Perhaps they would be best placed to answer your question.

Comment: I do not know exactly, because I solve exercises from different years for exam preparation.

Comment: So basically there is no syntax or build error issue. Your question seeks a subjective opinion as to why your working solution might be preferred over "the solution they uses". Such questions are generally considered to be out of scope for SO. You may get a better response by posting this question on the Software Engineering Stack Exchange.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the bad formulation. I will change it. Oh thanks-it is changed :-)

Comment: Maybe such a subjective question is a better fit for CodeReview?

Comment: If you expect some threads to work faster than others, `dynamic` is not a bad choice

Comment: I would argue `static` is a better fit for this example, due to the simplicity of the calculations inside the loop and the fact that you expect them all to take just about the same amount of time. The chunksize however is a bit more important, the choice of 8 is done to avoid false-sharing (or so I would assume) and should provide a reasonable improvement in performance, particularly here where there are very few operations in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution likely did it for one of two reasons: there is another nowait loop nearby that is imbalanced and might create a case in which threads reach this loop out of order, or they were worried about running on a system with a great deal of interference that is variable by core.  Using `schedule(dynamic)` is materially more expensive, for now until runtimes actually implement `nonmonotonic` properly, so `static` is the clear choice as long as the workload is balanced, which this snippet is.  The only reason to use dynamic here would be if imbalance between threads were expected to come from somewhere else, either in the code or from interfering workloads.